# How to add user-data in JOOMLA?

Tags: joomla

i wannt to build a website with user management. User should be able to loggin with different accounts, f.e. GMail, Facebook, .....
When the user is logged in he/she can upload pictures with geolocation data and some text. 
All uploaded geolocations should be visualized on something like google-maps.
Unregisterd users can view the map, but can not change the data or upload anything.

To solve this requirement i decided to use JOOMLA 2.5. with the "plugin_googlemap_J25_J3x.v3.2" plugin.

Everything i know about JOOMLA is what i learned the last two days.So i am very new to it.
Currently i am stuck, because i do not know how to save the user-data (pictures with geolocation data and some text) in JOOMLA.

I asked google! For more than an hour now! Could not find anything, related to that topic!

So my concrete questions are:

1. I suppose it is not possible to extend the JOOMLA user data database with the user-data, or?
2. If this is not possible, than i need a second database which holds the user-data, or?
3. Does anyone knows a tutorial which solves this problem?

I found someting for wordpress "http://codecanyon.net/item/privatecontent-user-data-addon/2399731" 
but i have to check if this solves my requirements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First make a list of your requirement then go to JED(Joomla extension Directory). search for related extensions.

Here from your requirement ,

1. You need a Customized [Joomla Registration form](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/23805)
2. [Social Media logins](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/22343)

And so on, so check the details of requirement and extension available, In any way you may need some customization on the Application then you can create some plugins for [Users](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) events.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you, but currently i think its not possible with JOOMLA! The Problem is how to know which user added which data! There are plugins for special user data, like movies (extendDB) or persons, but there is no plugin which handles ANY userdata. So in my case pictures with geolocation and some text.